# Accessing property VS saving locally

Tags: c#, optimization

Let's say I have a class `MyClass` which has a property `int Property { get; }` and thus is a read-only property.

Now in another class I have a for loop which performs a task similar to this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < something; ++i)
    someArray[myClass.Property + i] = something;
```

I expect the `myClass` to be a reference to an object which has another reference to `Property`, thus I expect to have two reads in memory (and memory is a well known bottleneck).

My question is: is the compiler that smart that actually recognizes the read-only property and, noticing it is required multiple times stores locally the reference for quick access or implementing a solution like the following would save a memory access?

```
var tempProperty = myclass.Property;
for (var i = 0; i < something; ++i)
    someArray[tempProperty + i] = something;
```

I tried to take a look to IL but then I realized I don't really understand what does it do.

PS: I know that such a micro-optiomization would save very little time, but that cycle has something like 1.000.000 iterations and I'm working on a very time-critical environment, so if it actually saves some time it would be good (besided if the compiler is smarter than me, I'll go with first solution).

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the property. Trivial properties get inlined and possibly subsequently optimized further. Look at the asm to confirm (make sure to disable "suppress optimizations")

Comment: I tried to take a look to the IL, but I had no clue on what it actually did unfortunately

Comment: The IL is nearly irrelevant, all the interesting optimizations are done by the JIT compiler.

Comment: If you care at all, you should write the code the second way. The JIT *might* optimize the first version into the second, but there are no guarantees. Even if you determine that it does on the current version of the optimizer, it may not on another version of the optimizer. The 32-bit and 64-bit versions are quite different beasts. There is nothing semantically or readability-wise wrong with the second snippet. In fact, it is arguably *more* clear and explicit about what is going on.